# Force.com IDE (Eclipse) connection issues

Tags: api, force.com, eclipse, developer

Our team is having an issue saving classes/pages to the server through Force.com IDE. It is an org-wide issue and not connected to their credentials/IP access/profile/API rights/connectivity issue.

Restarting Eclipse/laptops, creating a new project, cleaning the project, cleaning cache(DNS,system,user) are some of the ideas we tried and didn't work. Any thoughts?

[image: Screenshot from Mac].

We also see the following error in the logs:

> "Unable to get authorization info - endpoint is null or empty"

Comment: Turn off the Firewall in Mac's Privacy and Security settings or allow eclipse through it.

Comment: Firewall was off and we still have the issue

Comment: Everything was working perfectly until Sunday and all of a sudden, we are having this issue.

Comment: I have following configuration working: Force.com IDE plugin version 33.0 installed on Eclipse Juno. OS X 10.10 Yosemite. Java: Apple legacy java runtime and JDK 7 update 8 installed. This is working fine for me on LAN and WiFi

Comment: One more question: is it for one org or all orgs?

Comment: We have tried another user from another org and it worked on the Windows machine and not on the Mac. Looks like for some reason Mac Eclipse is not able to reach Salesforce.

Comment: Try this, Download or copy a clean zip of eclipse, put it in different directory from the previous, install force.com ide by url given on salesforce plugin installation guide. And the try to create new project. In addition to it check that you can access Salesforce from other apps like mavensmate for sublime and chrome browser also.

Comment: We can access SF through ANT. So it must be an Eclipse config. We are trying a clean install. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-Click on the project name in Eclipse -> Force.com -> Project Properties -> Force.com

We had set the environment to Production/Developer, which was redirecting to www.salesforce.com instead of login.salesforce.com (Not sure how that was changed). We selected "other" and specified login.salesforce.com as the host.

You cannot login to www.salesforce.com. It must be a salesforce subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue on Windows 7 / Eclipse Kepler.  Sandbox orgs seem to work ok.  Have a case into salesforce.

Comment: Look at my answer above.

Comment: Back in business - thanks for posting your answer.  I think something changed on salesforce's end and not in eclipse since I had a browser bookmark to get to the login page using something like: www.salesforce.com/login.jsp?un=xxx@xxx.com which stopped working at the same time of the eclipse issue

Comment: Looks like salesforce fixed something.  I am now able to create a project against an org using the regular production/developer setting which was not working yesterday without the manual host work-around

Comment: We tried it yesterday and it looks like production/developer looks at login.salesforce.com after you change it once manually. So I think it's Eclipse being smart, not SF fixing something.

Answer (score 0):

Very first check for any active firwall/antivirus software into your network.

If there is active firewall/antivirus software, then deactivate/disable it.

And then try.

If issue still persists then try it by changing your network.
You can use any netsetter or any different service provider internet.

It may help you out.

Answer (score -2):

There is a problem with SF and their IDE API on some orgs. We see this on Eclipse and on MeavenMate too. We've opened a case to salesforce.

This has been fix